# Session lost in .Net core when making fetch request from JS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When making request from JS to controller sessionvalue that is previously set gets lost. How do I prevent that? Below var instanceId returns null.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetEmails()
    {
        var instanceId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("instanceId");
        HttpContext.Items.Add("instanceId", instanceId);
        var result = someapicall;
        var returnObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        return Json(returnObj);
    }
```

The JS is just a standard fetch to said controller action.

Comment: Instead of depending on sessions to remember who the user was pass the ID as a parameter. Besides, you should *not* hard-code access to global objects like HttpContext that may or may not exist, eg during testing. Definitely not *inside* an action. You can *inject* a context in the controller's constructor but you *shouldn't*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your JavaScript `fetch`-request sends the ASP.NET Core cookies along with it? The session state uses a cookie to track and identify requests and load the correct data. If a request doesn't sends the cookie it won't be able to figure out which session the request is tied to.

Please refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#working-with-session-state) for more info about session state in ASP.NET Core.

**Edit**
For completeness: the solution is to add `credentials: true` for `fetch`-requests so it will send cookies along with the request. For example:

```
{ method: 'GET', credentials: 'include' }
```

For AJAX requests you should add the `withCredentials` property, which has the same purpose:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/some/url',
   // ...
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

Or set it globally, for all requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // ...
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I included: `{ method: 'GET', credentials: 'include' }` in my fetch and that solved it. Much appreciated!

Comment: That makes sense, you'll have to do the same when you use AJAX requests.